# MongoDB query to find an ID of a referenced model

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am trying to find an ID of a model which is referenced to another model.
I have a User model which consist of an array of challenges, I have to find an ID of a challenge  which exist for a particular user

My user model:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
image: String,
displayName: String,
firstName: String,
lastName: String,
password: String,
email: String,
createdAt: Date,
accessToken: String,
isLoggedIn: Boolean,

challenges:[
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"Challenge"
    }
]
});
```

My challenges model:

```
var  ChallengeSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
winner: Boolean,
score: String
});
```

For eg:
If my user id is 1 and challenge id is 89, I have to check if the challenge id is present for that particular user whose id is 1.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is document-oriented and don't have joins. In theory all data about one object is stored in one document in such dbs.
So in your case we have users with array of challenges inside.

Comment: I understand that but then how do I search if that challenge is present for that user or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query to check if the challenge id (89) is present for that particular user whose id is 1.

```
User.count({
    _id: 1, // User ID 
    challenges: {
        "$in": [89] // Challenge Id 
    }
}).exec(function(err, count){
    if(err){
        // Handle error
    } else {
        if(count > 0){
            // If count greater than 0 than user(ID-1) contains challenge(ID-89)
        }
    }
});
```